# How to set a specific json response object as a js var - Cloudinary

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, cloudinary

I am using Cloudinary to host my profile images that are set by users.

I'm mostly using PHP for my web application -> Here are the instructions as provided by Cloudinary http://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_image_upload#overview

The problem that I encounter is that I want to display the image directly after upload by parsing the newly created URL for the image that is returned by JSON.

When I do the console.log as provided by Cloudinary:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.cloudinary-fileupload').bind('cloudinarydone', function(e, data) {
           console.log(data);
           return true;
        });
    });
```

[This is the console.log response that I receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ua8kw.png)

Can anyone please help me with a javascript or JQuery function that I can use in order to display the updated image with in my image tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need read the tree...

```
jqXHR.responseJSON.url
```

In this case, use

```
data.result.url
```

See example of http://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_image_upload#preview_thumbnail_progress_indication_multiple_images

Comment: @ JohnHenrique, thanks for your response. The thing is I want to update the existing profile picture with the newly uploaded one. Your link refers to showing a preview which is not exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: You need see example of code "how to get url returned", more attention please. The return process is EVERY the same.

Comment: you must think I'm stupid or something. But thanks so much, I realised what you meant with your answer and was able to get the variable I required using the Console.log. now I just need to implement the replacement of the value.

Comment: You is using jQuery, right? To replace value of SRC image just use prop function. See documentation is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Can you update the `src` of your image tag based on the json returned?

Something like this in the callback function:

```
var imgDiv = document.getElementById("profile");
imgDiv.src = data.jqXHR.responseJSON.url;
```

Comment: @J S. I am relatively new to programming and would appreciate it if you could look at the returned code as provided in the image "This is the console.log response that I receive"[link]( https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ua8kw.png) to help me formulate some actual script specific to my situation.